# How can I get g-leaflet map to show immediately and without having to resize the window?

Tags: gwt, leaflet, gxt

I have a problem with g-leaflet - it shows as a grey rectangle only (with a bit of the map at top left) until I resize the window (manually). Then it shows up. Sometimes parts of maps show when I hover over an area but this too is incomplete and problematic. Here:

[image: This is how it looks]

The code that I use to add the G-Leaflet map to my GXT VerticalContainer (com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer) is as follows, taken from G-Leaflet example:

```
LeafletDrawResourceInjector.ensureInjected();
final MapWidget mapWidget = new MapWidget();
mapWidget.setSize("1000px", "750px"); // I added this myself to try to fix the issue
myVerticalLayout.add(mapWidget);
```

(I also set the size of the "myVerticalLayout" container).

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet is really finicky. Scheduling a defferred call to invalidateSize() was not enough. Had to make my own JavaScript call to its invalidateSize using setTimeout, also making sure that all the containers are attached before this happens. Only hen it would show.